# Что лучше для выделения памяти: brk или mmap?

Tags: linux, ассемблер, память, syscall

Необходимо реализовать динамическое распределение памяти, то бишь собственные `malloc()` и `realloc()`. Разобрался с логикой и теперь никак не могу решить, какой системный вызов лучше использовать: *brk* или *mmap*.

`Brk` изменяет размер кучи. Крайне прост в использовании. Но вот для `realloc()` придётся иногда ещё собственноручно копировать память.

`Mmap` отображает файл (или, с дескриптором -1, можно просто блок данных) на память и возвращает указатель на эту самую память. Получаем удобства в виде системных вызовов `munmap` (отвязать) и `mremap` (изменить размер существующего; система также выполнит копирование при необходимости).

Резонный вопрос: кого использовать? Основными факторами выступают быстродействие и эффективность (выделить как можно больше из доступной памяти).

Думается мне, (предположение) реализация `brk` проще, и он оттого шустрее, но ведь запрашивает непрерывную область памяти — загвоздка: ежели на пути встретится какая-нибудь память, используемая другими процессами, надо будет либо её сдвинуть, либо попросту отказать в предоставлении памяти. И тут кажется, что `mmap` побеждает, так как выполняет именно то, что нужно: ищет куски нужного размера и даёт на них указатель. Пишут также, что `brk` устарел.

Может, кто сталкивался. Есть кардинальное отличие? Предпочтительнее ли использовать одно взамен другого? Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предупреждаю сразу: это всего лишь теоретические измышления. Сам я писал аллокатор только когда проходил курс по операционным системам, и тот аллокатор был наипростейшим - односвязный список занятых и свободных блоков с аллокацией первого подходящего. Для такого тривиального аллокатора `sbrk` за глаза. Он хорош как учебное задание, и плох для реальной жизни: есть риск фрагментации памяти, и практически 100% гарантия, что процесс не будет возвращать память операционной системе.

В реальной жизни все используют `mmap`, даже самые маленькие:

- [PDClib](https://github.com/DevSolar/pdclib/blob/7d471427fa986a9f4cafb069af17821ee7868141/functions/_dlmalloc/malloc.c#L113)
- [µClibc](https://github.com/kraj/uClibc/blob/ca1c74d67dd115d059a875150e10b8560a9c35a8/libc/stdlib/malloc-standard/malloc.c#L345)
- [musl](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/malloc/mallocng/malloc.c#n42)
- [klibc](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/klibc/klibc.git/tree/usr/klibc/malloc.c#n141)

Разумеется, [glibc использует mmap](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/513331b788a3fa633f1d0417d43915e16a0c88f0/malloc/arena.c#L378)

Но ИМХО, выбор между `mmap` и `sbrk` для аллокатора сугубо вторичен. Можно и с mmap такого наворотить, что память быстро закончится.

В своей уже [классической статье](https://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) Дуг Ли (Doug Lea) выделяет несколько требований к аллокаторам:

> **Minimizing Space**: The allocator should not waste space: It should obtain as little memory from the system as possible, and should
> maintain memory in ways that minimize fragmentation -- ``holes''in
> contiguous chunks of memory that are not used by the program.
>
> **Minimizing Time**: The malloc(), free() and realloc routines should be as fast as possible in the average case.
>
> **Maximizing Tunability**: Optional features and behavior should be controllable by users either statically (via #define and the like) or
> dynamically (via control commands such as mallopt).
>
> **Maximizing Locality**: Allocating chunks of memory that are typically used together near each other. This helps minimize page and
> cache misses during program execution.
>
> **Maximizing Error Detection**: It does not seem possible for a general-purpose allocator to also serve as general-purpose memory
> error testing tool such as Purify. However, allocators should provide
> some means for detecting corruption due to overwriting memory,
> multiple frees, and so on.
>
> **Minimizing Anomalies**: An allocator configured using default settings should perform well across a wide range of real loads that
> depend heavily on dynamic allocation -- windowing toolkits, GUI
> applications, compilers, interpretors, development tools, network
> (packet)-intensive programs, graphics-intensive  packages, web
> browsers, string-processing applications, and so on.

Первичен алгоритм аллокации блоков и структура данных для индексирования блоков. Поэтому я бы начинал с этого. И в первую очередь ознакомился с `dlmalloc`, который до сих пор используют в `libc` для встроенных систем.

Что же касается собственно вашего вопроса, то `mmap` даёт всё, что можно получить от `sbrk`, и ещё немного сверху. Чем хорош mmap:

- можно сделать несколько независимых пулов. Например, пул для маленьких объектов очень удобен для борьбы с фрагментацией, чтобы не смешивать мелкие объекты с большими. Плюс возможны независимые аллокации для разных потоков (threads) - как минимум, можно автоматически подобрать всю висящую память после завершения потока
- для больших объектов можно сразу аллоцировать память из операционной системы, и вернуть её обратно после освобождения объекта